# first or filter function of swift array doesnt give the right reference object

Tags: swift

I have defined a struct in my viewcontroller before my viewdidload

```
struct CustomFilterButton {
var Id : Int = 0;
var Name : String = "";
var selected : Bool = false;
}
```

then I create reference for it in global

```
var customButtons = [CustomFilterButton]();
```

then in my viewdidload I appended some customFilterButton objects in customButtons array

```
customButtons.append(CustomFilterButton.init(Id: 1, Name: "A", selected: false))
customButtons.append(CustomFilterButton.init(Id: 2, Name: "B", selected: false))
customButtons.append(CustomFilterButton.init(Id: 3, Name: "C", selected: true))
customButtons.append(CustomFilterButton.init(Id: 4, Name: "D", selected: false))
```

in viewdidload or in any other function when I try to get an object in array using first or filter and change it, but it doesnt work.

```
    print(customButtons[0].selected);
    print("--")
    var bt = customButtons.first{
        $0.Id == 1
    }
    bt?.selected = true;
    print(bt?.selected);
    print(customButtons[0].selected);
```

here is the result

```
false
--
Optional(true)
false
```

the same applies to filter also!
Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong?

Note: I need to get the object that first or filter found and change it, not the hard copy of it

Comment: Be sure to check out my answer as I still feel like you're kinda missing the point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deal with a `Struct`, you have to understand that it is a value type.

So, that means that **everytime you pass a value around, it's a COPY of the value and not the reference**

And when you do this:

```
var bt = customButtons.first{
    $0.Id == 1
}
```

You're asking the compiler to retrieve a copy of the `CustomFilterButton` whose `Id` is 1 and assign the copy to your `bt` variable.

To tackle this, you can access the element by its index and directly modify its value without passing it around (assigning to a new variable)

```
// Get the index of the element you're trying to modify
if let indexYouWantToModify = customButtons.firstIndex(where: {$0.Id == 1}){
    // Modify it directly through its index 
    customButtons[indexYouWantToModify].selected = true
}
```

Oh, and though changing your `Struct` to a `Class` works for you, I think it's unnecessary just for this little use case. Structs and Classes hold their own benefits and trade-offs. I'm not sure what you're planning to do over this `CustomFilterButton` over the long run so I suggest you to read [this](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/difference-between-a-struct-and-a-class-in-swift-53e08df73714) article and decide for yourselves!

Answer (score 0):

```
var bt = customButtons.first{
   $0.Id == 1
}
```

At this moment `bt` has no any relation to your `customButtons[0]`, its value was copied.

Comment: so it creates another object, but isnt it supposed to work?

Comment: @smoothumut bt is not a reference, it's a hard copy of customButtons[0].

Comment: thanks for the comment, how can I reach to reference using first or filter?

Comment: get firstIndex, and reference though this index

Answer (score 0):

Access to item by index

```
    print(customButtons[0].selected);
    print("--")
    var offset = 0
    var bt = customButtons.enumerated().first{
        if $0.element.Id == 1 {
            offset = $0.offset
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    customButtons[offset].selected = true;
    print(customButtons[0].selected);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `class` instead of `struct`.

Comment: oh, no! I hava used those structs everywhere :( thanks for your time and answer, can you please tell why I should use class instead of struct

Comment: No, you are not. Apple recommends using of structs anywhere it's possible.

Comment: @smoothumut This answer is not necessarily true. I suggest you read more about 'Value types and Reference types' and the 'difference between `Class` and `Struct`' in general and you'll have a better understanding

Comment: you are right, class worked for this case. I am going to check that difference. thanks a lot for the answer